# MySQL: Update all variable of the same name

Tags: mysql, database

i would like to ask by using one mysql, how can i update the name "orange" become "oranges" and all the variable "fruit" in asc_category become "fruits"
[image]

this mysql only will change the variable name in specific asc_id row only.

```
$sql = "UPDATE food SET asc_maincategory = '$asc_maincategory', asc_subcategory = '$asc_subcategory' WHERE asc_id = '$asc_id' ";
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

we can do this:

```
UPDATE food
   SET asc_subcategory = 'oranges'
 WHERE asc_subcategory = 'orange'
;
```

and this:

```
UPDATE food 
   SET asc_maincategory = 'fruits'
 WHERE asc_maincategory = 'fruit'
;
```

---

All of the rows in `fruit` that satisfy the condition in the WHERE clause will have a new value assigned to the column.

---

***EDIT***

Q: "*Can using one mysql to run both process?*"

A: Yes, we can perform both of those operations in a single SQL statement. The SQL syntax is a bit more complicated.

Q: "*cause what i want is when user edit the name orange and fruit, mysql will update the name "orange" of that asc_id at the same time update all the "fruit" name in asc_maincategory become "fruits"*"

A: if I'm understanding the specification for the operation, it sounds like a dangerous operation to implement. But it could be done.

Write a SELECT statement first:

```
SELECT t.asc_id
     , t.asc_maincategory
     , t.asc_subcategory
     , 'fruits'                                          AS new_maincategory 
     , IF(t.asc_id=s.asc_id,'oranges',t.asc_subcategory) AS new_subcategory
  FROM ( SELECT f.asc_id
              , f.asc_maincategory
           FROM food f
          WHERE f.asc_id = '10001'
       ) s
  JOIN food t
    ON t.asc_maincategory = s.asc_maincategory
 ORDER BY t.asc_id
```

The inline view `s` identifies the row that with the specified value for `asc_id`, and returns the `asc_maincategory` of the current row. That is joined to the food table, to retrieve all rows with a matching `asc_maincategory`.

The expressions with alias like `new_` are returning the *new* values we want to assign to the columns. This expression:

```
IF(t.asc_id=s.asc_id,'oranges',t.asc_subcategory)
```

returns `'oranges'` for the row(s) with value of `'10001'` in `asc_id` (as specified in the inline view `s`.)  For other rows, it returns the current value of the `asc_subcategory` column.

If we assign the current value of a column back to the same column (on the same row), it results in no change. For example, if `bar` is a column in table `foo`, we can run this statement

```
UPDATE foo t
   SET t.bar = t.bar
```

to assign the *current* value of the column back to itself, resulting in no change to the column (barring the existence of any BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE triggers.)

Once we have a SELECT statement working, we can convert that into an UPDATE statement: replace `SELECT ... FROM` with the keyword `UPDATE` and add a `SET` clause.

```
UPDATE ( SELECT f.asc_id
              , f.asc_maincategory
           FROM food f
          WHERE f.asc_id = '10001'
       ) s
  JOIN food t
    ON t.asc_maincategory = s.asc_maincategory
   SET t.asc_maincategory = 'fruits'
     , t.asc_subcategory  = IF(t.asc_id=s.asc_id,'oranges',t.asc_subcategory)
```

---

**An important and (somewhat related final note:**

*NEVER* incorporate potentially unsafe values into SQL text.

Use prepared statements with bind placeholders, or properly escape values to make them safe for inclusion in SQL.

Exploits of a Mom (Little Bobby Tables):  https://xkcd.com/327/

OWASP SQL Injection:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Can using one mysql to run both process? cause what i want is when user edit the name orange and fruit, mysql will update the name "orange" of that asc_id at the same time update all the "fruit" name in asc_maincategory become "fruits"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using CASE... WHEN...THEN.

```
UPDATE food 
SET asc_subcategory = CASE
        WHEN asc_subcategory = 'orange' THEN 'oranges'
        ELSE asc_subcategory END,
    asc_maincategory = CASE
        WHEN asc_maincategory = 'fruit' THEN 'fruits'
        ELSE asc_maincategory
    END;
```

If asc_subcategory='orange',then update it to oranges else the same value from the DB.

And If asc_maincategory='fruit',then update it to fruits else the same value from the DB.

Comment: @Ichida please accept the answer if it suit for you